# Applescript to copy images from a folder on my desktop to excel column A

Tags: excel, applescript

## **Summarize the Problem:**

I want to create an Applescript to paste images from a folder on my desktop to an excel column.  There are thousands of images so adding the photo into excel manually wouldn't work.

Let's say the folder has 500 images titled:
Image_1.jpg... Image_2.jpg.. ... Image_500.jpg

I would like these actual images in an excel file in Column B

It would look like this:

```
Column A          Column B
Image_1.jpg       Actual image of Image_1.jpg
Image_2.jpg       Actual image of Image_2.jpg
...               ...
Image_500.jpg     Actual image of Image_500.jpg
```

I don't need anything fancy that counts how many images are in a folder or anything, but I just don't know how to tell excel to paste image 1, then move down one row, paste the second etc.  Should be centered to the cells too.

I can manually change how many rows.. so If I have 382 images or 1382 images, I can manually type that into the script for that specific folder, and change the qty for the next time I run it if its a different amount of photos.

I'm basically making a spec sheet on excel where I can do Title, and in the next column, the actual photograph of that.

## **Provide background including what you've already tried**

I've already tried a few options on filePath, imagefolder, Imagelist but none work.

## **Show some code**

So far the only thing that's worked is pasting one individual image.  I was going to just do this, and copy paste that same line changing it from Image_1.jpg to 2,3,4,...500... but might be too time consuming.

This method also only inserts the photo as a tiny square swatch instead of a legible image.

```
set theFilePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:Christian:Desktop:ImageFolder:Image_1.jpg"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
make new picture at end with properties {file name:theFilePath}

    end tell
end tell
```

## **Describe expected and actual results including any error messages**

Errors I keep getting are:

Microsoft Excel got an error: Can’t make class picture." number -2710 from picture to class

Comment: Question: Excel doesn't actually store pictures in cells. The best it can do is out a picture in the worksheet aligned with a particular cell. Is that sufficient? it will be purely visual (e.g., you won't be able query a cell programmatically to retrieve an image). Also, there would have to be some scaling of images. What size would you like to aim for in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should do the trick, more or less.

```
set imageFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder)

tell application "System Events"
    set imageList to POSIX path of files of folder imageFolder whose visible is true
end tell

set targetImageHeight to 140
set largestImageWidth to 0

set imageCount to count of imageList
set idx to 1
repeat with imageFile in imageList
    set targetImageWidth to widthOfPic(imageFile, targetImageHeight)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        set nameCell to cell ("A" & idx as string) of worksheet 1 of workbook 1
        set value of nameCell to my imageName(imageFile)
        set imageCell to cell ("B" & idx as string) of worksheet 1 of workbook 1
        set theLeft to left position of imageCell
        set theTop to (top of imageCell)

        set newPic to make new picture at beginning of worksheet 1 of workbook 1 with properties {file name:POSIX file imageFile, height:targetImageHeight, width:targetImageWidth, top:theTop, left position:theLeft, placement:placement move}

        set row height of imageCell to targetImageHeight
        if targetImageWidth > largestImageWidth then
            set largestImageWidth to targetImageWidth
            -- this next line is purely cosmetic, to make it look
            -- like the image is in the cell
            set column width of imageCell to largestImageWidth * 0.1625
        end if
    end tell
    set idx to idx + 1
end repeat

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet 1 of workbook 1
        tell column "A:A"
            autofit
            set vertical alignment to vertical alignment center
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

on imageName(imagePath)
    tell application "System Events"
        return name of file imagePath
    end tell
end imageName

on widthOfPic(picPath, targetH)
    set sipsOutput to do shell script "sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth " & quoted form of picPath
    set h to (last word of paragraph 2 of sipsOutput) as integer
    set w to (last word of paragraph 3 of sipsOutput) as integer
    return targetH * w / h
end widthOfPic
```

Comment: Sorry I missed your earlier comment - yes this is PERFECT you are amazing.  Thanks a million!!